# Forcing Build to throw an error when dependency is missing

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops

We use Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) to automatically build our code and deploy it afterwards.

Because we ran out of build minutes, we added a local build agent. After (sucessfully) building and deploying we received an error message on the final product.

It took us a while to add more logging, to find out, that a dependency was missing. (to be precise: Microsoft.IdentityModel, which is not a nuget-library)

We know how to add that missing library to the build machine.

But I would deeply prefer that the build itself already breaks and tell me that a reference is missing instead of just telling me: "Everything is fine" and ignoring the missing dll.

Is there a way to configure that?

Comment: Is the dependency required during the build? If yes, the build should fail with error log indicate that the dependency is missing.

Comment: A possible scenario is that the required dependency is installed your build machine but isn't installed on your product machine, then the build won't fail since it can get the dependency.

Comment: It was a complete different scenario. On local build, Copy Local was set to "true", on the build agent it wasn't

Comment: Is the dependency registered in GAC? If yes, then it won't be copied to local.

Comment: Any update to this? For legacy issues we are using devenv from VS2005. We build a project from commandline and it succeeds but a dependency project is missing. We like it to actually fail.